# Showing xml for correct view

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-recyclerview

When a user logs in to my app, they can either click the `view students` button or `daily grading` button. The `view students` will display a student's image and their name. The `daily grading` will display the student's image, name, and two checkboxes that says pass or fail. Now the issue I have is that the checkboxes for pass and fail are showing up in my `activity_view_students.xml` view when it should not be. It should only show when a user clicks `daily grading`. I will put images below to make it clearer

What it looks like in the `activity_view_students.xml`

[image: What it looks like]

What it should look like in `activity_view_students.xml`

[image: What it should look like]

I will paste all relevant code below.

`ViewStudents.java`

```
package com.example.studenttracker;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.Query;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Comparator;


public class ViewStudents extends AppCompatActivity {


    RecyclerView recyclerView;
    Button addStudent;


    private DatabaseReference myRef;

    public ArrayList<Students> students;
    private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;
    private Button orderStudents;

    private EditText mEditTextAge;
    private EditText mEditTextAssignment;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_students);

        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        addStudent = findViewById(R.id.addStudentButton);
        mEditTextAge = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAge);
        mEditTextAssignment = findViewById(R.id.EditTextAssignment);
        orderStudents = findViewById(R.id.orderStudents);

        addStudent.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(ViewStudents.this, AddStudent.class));
            }
        });

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(this, 2));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        myRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

        students = new ArrayList<>();

        ClearAll();

        GetDataFromFirebase();



    }
    private void GetDataFromFirebase() {
        Query query = myRef.child("student");

        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                ClearAll();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    Students student = new Students();
                    if (snapshot.child("url").getValue() == null) {
                        student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("imageUrl").getValue().toString());
                    }
                    else {
                        student.setImageUrl(snapshot.child("url").getValue().toString());

                    }
//                    student.setAge(mEditTextAge.getText().toString());
//                    student.setAssignment(mEditTextAssignment.getText().toString().trim());
                    student.setName(snapshot.child("name").getValue().toString());
                    students.add(student);
                }
                recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), students);
                recyclerView.setAdapter(recyclerAdapter);
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
    private void ClearAll() {
        if (students != null) {
            students.clear();

            if(recyclerAdapter != null) {
                recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
        students = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void orderStudents(View view) {
        Collections.sort( students, new Comparator<Students>() {
            @Override
            public int compare( Students o1, Students o2 ) {
                return o1.name.compareTo( o2.name );
            }
        });
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }

}
```

`RecyclerAdapter.java`

```
package com.example.studenttracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class RecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;
    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    private static final String Tag = "RecyclerView";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList;

    public RecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.studentsArrayList = studentsArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_student_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
//TextView
        holder.textView.setText(studentsArrayList.get(position).getName());

        Glide.with(mContext).load(studentsArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);

// if (studentsArrayList.get(position).get) { //check if you need the buttons or not
// holder..setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// holder.checkBox2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
// } else {
// holder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// holder.checkBox2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
// }
    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentsArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_view_students.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ViewStudents">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="1dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" >

    </androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/addStudentButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:text="Add Students"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/orderStudents"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="orderStudents"
        android:text="Order Students"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`daily_grading.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".DailyGrading">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="409dp"
        android:layout_height="729dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`activity_student_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".DailyGrading">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="52dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/passc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView"
            android:text="PASS" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/failc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passc"
            android:text="FAIL" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`GradingRecyclerAdapter`

```
package com.example.studenttracker;

import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class GradingRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GradingRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private OnItemClickListener mListener;


    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }
    public void setOnItemClickListener(OnItemClickListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }
    private static final String Tag = "RecyclerView";
    private Context mContext;
    private ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList;

    public GradingRecyclerAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<Students> studentsArrayList) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.studentsArrayList = studentsArrayList;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public GradingRecyclerAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.activity_grading_student_item,parent,false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
//TextView
        holder.textView.setText(studentsArrayList.get(position).getName());

        Glide.with(mContext).load(studentsArrayList.get(position).getImageUrl()).into(holder.imageView);


    }
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return studentsArrayList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ImageView imageView;
        TextView textView;
        Button passButton;
        Button failButton;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            textView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            passButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.PASS);
            failButton = itemView.findViewById(R.id.FAIL);

//            passButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
//            failButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (mListener != null) {
                        int position = getAdapterPosition();

                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`activity_grading_student_item`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    tools:context=".DailyGrading">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
        app:cardElevation="2dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="5dp"

        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="52dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="200dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:paddingTop="20dp"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/PASS"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView"
            android:text="PASS" />

        <CheckBox
            android:id="@+id/FAIL"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/textView"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/PASS"
            android:text="FAIL" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: that's not related to the XML you included it's about the activity_student_item.XML

Comment: not sure what you mean @ahmednader

Comment: include your activity_student_item.xml file?

Comment: I have added please take a look @ahmednader

Comment: alright check my answer and mark as answer if it helps :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use different adapters
create another activity_student_item.xml let's say activity_view_student_item.xml and remove the checkboxes from that one
create another adapter for that recyclerView but change

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_student_item,parent,false);
```

in the new adapter to

```
View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.activity_view_student_item,parent,false);
```

and in the ViewStudents activity set the recycler's Adapter to that new adapter

Comment: one sec trying to implement your solution

Comment: can you check if I am doing it right. I added the `GradingRecyclerAdapter` and `activity_grading_student_item.xml` which I think show's what you are saying. @ahmed nader

Comment: can you take a look when you have a chance @ahmed nader

Comment: @CodeMonkey yes but still you need to assign that adapter to the recyclerView 
in ViewStudents.java instead of using RecyclerAdapter use GradingRecyclerAdapter

Comment: @CodeMonkey
you have 2 lines must change >>>> 
         
`private RecyclerAdapter recyclerAdapter;`

AND 
>>>  
`recyclerAdapter = new RecyclerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), students);`

change `RecyclerAdapter` to `GradingRecyclerAdapter`

Comment: with the changes you just said it puts the buttons on the wrong view.

Comment: @CodeMonkey let's talk in chat

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218651/discussion-between-codemonkey-and-ahmed-nader).

Comment: I am in chat now @ahmed nader

Comment: Thank you for all your help on resolving my issues @ahmed nader